# how to play sound that will continue changing-Pygame

Tags: audio, pygame

i am creating a program  for my little brother on pygame where numbers 1-20 will come up in order and each number will be pronounced by mp3 files which i have already created.what i am stuck on now is how to make it so that the sound being played for each number will change as the next button is pressed. i didn't want do it one by one as it will take too long. is there a way to make like a list of all the mp3 sounds  together so that the sounds played matches the number showing on the screen.

Sorry it was a long question. This is my first time asking a question and i couldn't find a way  to shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to put the sounds into a list and use the number as the index.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

SOUNDS = [
    pg.mixer.Sound('1.mp3'),
    pg.mixer.Sound('2.mp3'),
    pg.mixer.Sound('3.mp3'),
    ]

def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    number = 0

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                # Just use the number as the index.
                SOUNDS[number].play()
                # Increment the number and keep it in the range.
                number += 1
                number %= len(SOUND_LIST)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        print(number)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```